# Determine google application remaining global quota

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

In the google applications developer console I can see the global quota usage for a google API:

[image]

I would like to achieve the following:

1. Be able to programatically query the remaining quota, to ensure that important tasks can always be completed.
2. Receive some form of alert when we are approaching the quota limit.

So far I have tried configuring the 'Monitoring' section of the developer console, but all I can see are uptime checks. This question has also been asked in other areas of the interwebs but no-one has ever received an answer.

Answer (score 1):

At this time there is no API for checking the quota on the Google Developer console.

Comment: How about some way of getting notified when, e.g. <10% of the quota is remaining?

Comment: nope nothing.  The best i have managed to do myself was to create an application google Analytics account and log usage of the API to that and then i can track how many requests i am making myself.